# What's the web socket port of tezos node?

Tags: node

I've setup the tezos node for ghostnet and I want to subscribe to the new operations I don't know what's the port number for web socket, because 8732 is for RPC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such websocket port provided by octez-node. The tzflow.com service has its own intermediary server that reads new operations from a node's RPC and forwards those to web clients over websockets that it provides.